# Can we have supersymmetry using real scalar instead of complex scalars?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry

I am aware that a suersymmetric theories containing a complex scalar a Weyl fermion and an auxiliary field exist.

I was wondering if we can have something analogous using real and not complex scalar fields, and some kind of real Weyl fermions (if such a thing does indeed exist).

Comment: "Real fermion" is usually what one calls a *Majorana*, not a Weyl fermion.

Comment: @ACuriousMind i know. But just as we can have real four component spinors (aka Majorana), i thought that maybe an anlogous thing is possible with two component spinors. This is what I meant with real Weyl spinor

Comment: We do have "Majorana-Weyl spinors", but only in dimensions that are $8k+2$ for a natural number $k$.